# Java8 - merge and update list of objects

Tags: java-8, stream

I have two Lists containing objects of this class:

```
public class AObj
{
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private String value;


    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode()
    {
        return this.code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code)
    {
        this.code= code;
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value)
    {
        this.value= value;
    }

    
}
```

Now I would like to merge two lists into new list of type AObj based on condition:

1. if elements in list 2 not exist in first, then added
2. if at least one element in list2 exists in list 1 update only changed property

Basically, if i have the following list:

```
ArrayList<AObj> list1= new ArrayList[
AObj{name='a', code=1, value='a'}
AObj{name='b', code=2, value='ss'}
AObj{name='c', code=5, value='c'}]

ArrayList<AObj> list2= new ArrayList[
AObj{name='b', code=2, value='l2'}
AObj{name='d', code=6, value='c7'}]

ArrayList<AObj> list 3= new ArrayList[
AObj{name='a', code=1, value='a'}
AObj{name='b', code=2, value='l2'}
AObj{name='c', code=5, value='c'}
AObj{name='d', code=6, value='c7'}]
```

I tried to use stream, but this works only if both list have the same elements:

Thank you!

```
 List<AObj> newAList= list2.stream()
                .map(l1-> list1.stream()
                        .filter(i -> i.getCode().equals(consent.getCode()))
                        .peek(s -> s.setValue(l1.getValue()))
                        .findAny().orElse(l1))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to be able to just upsert `list2` items over `list1` items.
Why not just try to merge the two lists?

Something like,

```
Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(AObj::getCode, a -> a, (a, b) -> b))
        .values();
```

Here you iterate over `list1` first construct a `Map` (with `code` as the key) and then process `list2` items one at a time if there is a key collision (i.e. the key already exists), then replace the value with the item in the `list2`.

One limitation with this approach is that if you parallelize (with `.parallel()` after the `concat`) the stream, you might end up with unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Java 8 stream :**

**Logic:**

Here, I have created a final list by combining the given two list using `addAll` function and then created a map with this list using the `Collectors.toMap` with the merger function i.e. use the latest value in map corresponding to the key while creating the map and then collect the final list using `Collectors.collectingAndThen` as shown in the code below:

**Code:**

```
public class ListToAdd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<AObj> listFinal = new ArrayList<>();

        List<AObj> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add(new AObj("a","1","aVal"));
        list1.add(new AObj("b","2","bVal"));
        list1.add(new AObj("c","3","cVal"));
        list1.add(new AObj("d","4","dVal"));

        List<AObj> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add(new AObj("a","1","aValNew"));
        list2.add(new AObj("c","3","cValNew"));

        listFinal.addAll(list1);
        listFinal.addAll(list2);

        listFinal = listFinal.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(AObj::getCode,
                                    Function.identity(),(a, b) -> b),
                            m -> m.values().stream().toList()));
        System.out.println(listFinal);

    }
```

**Output:**

```
[AObj{name='a', code='1', value='aValNew'}, 
AObj{name='b', code='2', value='bVal'}, 
AObj{name='c', code='3', value='cValNew'}, 
AObj{name='d', code='4', value='dVal'}]
```